# Symfony2 Session - cannot find value

Tags: symfony

I'm sure that this problem is just due to a missed configuration parameter and that there is a simple answer to this, but it is driving me insane. Everything works as expected on our development machines, but on our test server, we have the following problem...

We've got a Symfony2 (version 2.5.7) application. A controller sets a session variable to hold the ID of an entity. The app then fires off Ajax requests and the controller that receives the requests uses the session variable to decide what to send back.

In the main controller, we have (after checking that $page is a valid entity)

```
$this->get('session')->set('pageId', $page->getId());
```

and then in the controller that handles the ajax, we have

```
$pageId = $this->get('session')->get('pageId');
```

On loading the main controller, I can see that a session cookie has been set and it has the expected value for 'pageId'. I can see details of the session being stored in the app/session directory on the server, so I'm pretty certain that the session is being set correctly. The permissions are correct on this folder, so apache is allowed to read and write to it. But, the Ajax controller reports that $pageId is false. If I get the ID of the session;

```
$session = $this->get('session');
$session->start();
$sessionId = $session->getId();
```

I can see that the ID of the session matches the value in the cookie sent with the Ajax request, and matches a file called 'sess_{sessionId}' in the app/session directory.

What I am missing?

Comment: Have you tried with `$this->getRequest()->getSession();` ?

Comment: Sorry, as of Symfony 2.4, `getRequest()` is deprecated. Use it as a parameter of your controller method instead : `public function myAction(Request $request)`

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that manually deleting all files from the app/session directory solved the problem. I have no idea why, but it did solve it.